# SQL Oracle - Select more than 1000 rows from file

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with a query in which a file containing over 1000 rows is loaded.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE items IN(%NewListVar%)
```

The database returns this error:

> [Ora]ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000

Is it possible to divide loading rows or workaround this limit?

Comment: But how to set row value for file (%NewListVar%)?

Comment: If the values are in a file, how do you get them into the database?

Answer (score 1):

Insert values into temp table and then join the temp table on this values